# How to using jtable plugin in codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to use jtable plugin in framework codeigniter but i got a problem. I'm confused how to pass variable from view (jtable javascript code) to controller and to pass json_encode from controller to view.

Here are my code.

in my view page(Attendance_view.php).

[html code]

```
<input style="width:100px" type="text" id="from" name="from" value="<?php echo date("Y-m")."-01";?>">
```

[js code]

```
//Prepare jTable
var base_url ="<?=base_url()?>";
$('#TableContainer').jtable({
    title: 'Attendance',
    paging: true,
    sorting: true,
    defaultSorting: 'month ASC',
    selecting: true, //Enable selecting
    multiselect: true, //Allow multiple selecting
    selectingCheckboxes: true, //Show checkboxes on first column

    actions: {
        listAction: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/Attendance_controller/listRecord',
        createAction: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/Attendance_controller/create',
        updateAction: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/Attendance_controller/update',
        deleteAction: '<?=base_url()?>index.php/AttendanceAbsensi_controller/delete'
    },
            ....//another field here
});
//Load attendance from server
$('#TableContainer').jtable('load',{
        month:$("#from").val()
});
```

in my controller(Attendance_controller.php)

```
function listRecord()
{
    $this->load->model('Attendance_action');
    $jTableResult=$this->Attendance_action->list_record();
    $data['jTableResult']= json_encode($jTableResult);
    $this->load->view('Attendance_view',$data['jTableResult']);

}
```

in my model (Attendance_action.php)

```
function list_record()
{
    //get post variable
    $date=$this->input->post('month');  // i can't get the value.

    //Get record count
    $result = //my query here[select "some data" from "mytable" where month='$date']
    $recordCount = mysql_num_rows($result);


        //Add all records to an array
        $rows = array();
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            $rows[] = $row;
        }

        //Return result to jTable
        $jTableResult = array();
        $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
        $jTableResult['TotalRecordCount'] = $recordCount;
        $jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
        return $jTableResult;
}
```

When i load the controller page, the error message from jtable occured "An error occured while communicating to the server". Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i want to share my code. Now the problem fixed. I just change the controller code like this. Add "exit();" in controller.

```
function index() 
{
    $this->load->view('Attendance_view');

}

function listRecord()
{
    $this->load->model('Attendance_action');
    $jTableResult=$this->Antendance_action->list_record();
    print_r(json_encode($jTableResult));
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why your using jtable .can you use Jquery Datatbles here having ignited Datatables Library using that one we can implement crud  functionality simple

you can interest please check it once the bellow url

https://github.com/IgnitedDatatables/Ignited-Datatables/

http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/server_side.html

https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/160896/

i am personal y like  jquery data-tables.just check it once

Answer (score 0):

First load view page in separate function .In that page you call call your crud Urls

Change like this your controller

```
function list()
{

    $this->load->view('Attendance_view');

}

function listRecord()
{
    $this->load->model('Attendance_action');
    $jTableResult=$this->Attendance_action->list_record();
     print_r(json_encode($jTableResult));


}
```

Note : Can you please check it once this here mentioned clearly how to implement this one

http://jtable.org/GettingStarted

Comment: Thanks for ur answers. i've used jtable plugin in PHP without framework MVC CodeIgniter and it worked well. But when I tried to implement jtable plugin in CodeIgniter i got this problem. I'm beginner in codeigniter. I've tried ur suggestion. when i load the controller/listRecord() the table didn't show. I just saw the json array like this "{"Result":"OK","TotalRecordCount":1,"Records":[{"0":"35","id":"35","1":"29","id_buku_absensi":"29","2":"o89","id_pegawai":"o89","3":"0"}]}"

Comment: can you please check it once  your browser console having any errors .please check your  id's properly & your js and css loading correct or not.....